# Variable Arguments with a symbol

Tags: ruby

I'm generally studying Ruby at the time. I want to create a variable length argument method, sort of like Ruby Rails validates method. It would be like :

```
my_method(var1, *list)
```

And i would want to call it like :

```
my_method(whatever_var, :values => ['1','2','3'])
```

Now, my question is, how is :values handled ? I see it in validates(in Rails), but i don't really understand the mechanics. Is this now a symbol that points to an array ? And how should it be handled inside my function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a hash(a popular Ruby idiom) as a last argument, in which you can store values with lists, strings, anything:

```
def my_method(var1, options={})
  options[:values] ||= []
  options[:names] ||= []

  #code
end
```

From there you can call:

```
my_method(whatever_arg, :values => ['1', '2', '3', '4'], :names => ['mike'])
```